# communicate from one ViewModel to Another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a ProductCategoryViewModel in which I have a treeView Control which I bind to a collection in my viewModel,On the treeView control has one Context Menu .When the Context menu is selected I open another window ,on the window has One Textbox and two buttons, Ok and Cancel,here the user can enter one category name on the textbox and when ok clicked I want to add the category into database ,also I want to close the window and populate the ProductCategoryViewModel's CategoryCollection (to reflect the changes) these are my requirement.

My problem is :

1-Is I need to create a seperate viewModel for the new Window, and write code which add category into the database  ,or just Create one string property and two Commands for the buttons, ok and cancel in my ProductCategoryViewModel ,and write insert logic in there,
when the Ok Command invoked .

2-If I create a new ViewModel for the Window how do I communicate(to refresh the CategoryCollection  ) with my ProductCategoryViewModel .

Comment: New window - new vm. To communicate, pass instance (in new window vm constructor).

Comment: could you share some code what you have done so far, it is little difficult to get the picture from description.

Answer (score 1):

1. Definitely up to you. I would not write logic for implementing the
   insertion to the DB in my viewmodel, but maybe let a lower level
   dedicated worker handle it for you (maybe look into the [`Repository Pattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)
2. I have had good experience using the [`EventAggregator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) from [`Prism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648612.aspx). It is easy as registering the `EventAggregator` in one
   ViewModel and invoking your event (in your example, it would be
   adding to the `CatergoryCollection`:

   ```
   //Subscribe
   eventAggregator.GetEvent<CategoryUpdated>().Subscribe(ExitMethod);

   // Publish
   eventAggregator.GetEvent<CategoryUpdated>().Publish();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Started as a comment, and kept growing ...so here we go:

1. This doesn't sound like an issue, but more like a lack of knowledge, and might not adhere to the site's rules for questions.
2. Having said that, if you're using a framework (like mvvm-light), they usually have a messenger exactly for that.
3. Have a look at my [big mvvm template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768427/The-big-MVVM-Template). You can easily pick what you need from there, and get the idea of how to use the messenger class as well.

Depending on the complexity and your scope, sometimes a simple hack (string and a couple commands) is a valid option.

I'm sure I've seen a popup implementation for MVVM on the codeproject as well ...maybe you should have a look for that as well...

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://mvvmandunity.codeplex.com/releases/view/33806) can be helpful for beginning :).I would rather take first approach, because it's easier to write unit test for viewModel.